# Email etiquette - when to reply/threads and cc'd chains

Tags: professionalism, email

I emailed Joe in a different department for help/lots of questions on a new project. Basically "do you have info on this or do you know someone who does"? Joe responded saying "I'm sure Liz can help you, she knows all about this. I've cc'd her on this email"

How do I proceed? I want to thank Joe for putting me in touch with the right person, should I do so separately?  Do I reply all and thank Joe while also introducing myself to Liz? Do I email Liz separately and ask for her help or wait for her to reply in the chain since she now has my original email with the questions I asked?

Note: I'm an entry level employee who was told to reach out to this other department. I don't know these people and they are in higher up positions than I am so I want to be extra respectful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In this situation, I recommend thanking Joe and moving him to BCC on the thread. Then continue the conversation with Liz.

> Thank you Joe for recommending I speak with Liz. I'm moving you to BCC.
>
> Hi Liz, It's very nice to e-meet you! [Summarize the problem] Would you be the right person to help me?
>
> Thank you, [your name]

**EDIT:** 
Why BCC instead of CC Joe? BCCing Joe closes off the thread with him and repurposes the thread's context with Liz. Joe will get an email that shows his part is done and when Liz replies he won't get her response (or any response after that). This is especially useful in preventing abuse of reply-all in emails.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd BCC Joe? Why is that better than CC or just leaving Joe off further emails?

Comment: BCCing Joe closes off the thread with him and repurposes the thread's context with Liz. Joe will get an email that shows his part is done and when Liz replies he doesn't have to get her response (or any response after that)  I used to do this a lot when I worked as a Product Manager at a startup.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So when Joe is BCCd, if Liz selects reply he won't be on any further emails?

Comment: @Grace That's right!

Answer (score 0):

> "Thanks, Joe and Liz!  I am new with the company, so please bear with me!  Thank you both for your help - I will be sure to contact Liz in the future if I have any questions."

It keeps the question very straightforward and simple, states to Joe *'now that I know who to contact, I'll contact them in the future'* and gives them respect.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't Reply All when a specific person is needed. Instead I'd reply to Joe only, tell him thanks. Then I would write a new email to Liz explaining that I talked to Joe and if Liz could help. I feel this is the best approach to get a response. I found people just ignore chain emails when more people are cc'd as the conversation grows.